# Laravel Caching the Eloquent

Tags: caching, laravel

What is the difference between caching an Eloquent model with

```
$myResult = Model::remember(5)->get();
```

and using the `Cache` itself:

```
$myResult = Cache::remember('myModel', 5, function(){
    return Model::get();
});
```

Are they identical, or is each used for a different purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are caching the same thing - but in two different ways. They are technically identical (the same query result is cached in both examples for 5 minutes) - but they are different from a "separation of concerns" issue.

When you deal with a Model - perhaps it is in your controller - your Controller should have no real knowledge of the 'inner' workings of the Model. It should just ask for information, and be given the right information.

So using your examples - we have two ways a controller could be built:

Firstly - we could let the controller know "too much" and do this:

```
function showUser($id)
{
    $myResult = Cache::remember('myModel', 5, function(){
        return Model::find($id);
    });
}
```

In this example - the controller knows the inner works of the model, and it is also dictating how long the cache should be. But the controller should have no knowledge of what a user is, or how long it should be cached for - that is best left up to the Model to manage. i.e. what happens if you look for a user elsewhere in your code - you have to duplicate you caching.

Meanwhile you could do it this way instead:

```
function showUser($id)
{
      $user= User::getUser($id);
}
```

and then in your User Model

```
function getUser($id)
{
      return User::remember(5)->find($id);
}
```

This way the management of the user remains inside the model. The model knows how long (if at all) a user should be cached for. *(Yes - some people will say caching should be abstracted from the model into a repository - but lets keep it simple for now).* In this example the controller has no idea that the result is cached - *but it doesnt need to nor should it* - all it needs is the user with an id of `$id`

Comment: @Kousha - did my answer solve your question? Please accept some answers from some of your previous questions.

Comment: `your Controller should have no real knowledge of the 'inner' workings of the Model. It should just ask for information, and be given the right information.` <- This! thanks dude! great read